# Using mongoose to provide rest api for my C++ application?

Tags: c++, c, web-services, rest, mongoose-web-server

I want to use mongoose for exposing rest apis from inside my aplication. However, I do not see any model of how this can be implemented.

**Does anyone knows if it's possible of feasible to do using mongoose?**

**Can any exemple be provided demonstrating a simple case of it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used mongoose to implement an HTTP interface to a Windows service in C++. It was fairly straightforward to wrap mongoose in a set of C++ classes. It's easy to retrieve request information and generate output streams. I used [Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) to implement connection streams so that request handlers could use a std::ostream interface to write results back to the connection.

Use the `set_uri_callback()` function to define a handler for every possible request.

In each handler get the request type (GET, PUT, POST, etc.) and parameters.

Write the appropriate result back to the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I do not see set_uri_callback on mongoose for c++.

Comment: @ClaudioJunior: I didn't realize there was a mongoose for C++. I used the C API.